# The timing-driven placement phase encountered an error

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, error

Could someone explain inexperienced VHDL coder what this error message trying to tell me in simple words? I found a similar question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/118546/routing-errors-when-trying-to-implement-pll-onto-spartan-6-fpga-board), but here was no answer to it:

```
   ERROR:Place:1108 - A clock IOB / BUFGMUX clock component pair have been found
   that are not placed at an optimal clock IOB / BUFGMUX site pair. The clock
   IOB component <HREF> is placed at site <A4>. The corresponding BUFG component
   <HREF_IBUF_BUFG> is placed at site <BUFGMUX_X2Y3>. There is only a select set
   of IOBs that can use the fast path to the Clocker buffer, and they are not
   being used. You may want to analyze why this problem exists and correct it.
   If this sub optimal condition is acceptable for this design, you may use the
   CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE constraint in the .ucf file to demote this message to a
   WARNING and allow your design to continue. However, the use of this override
   is highly discouraged as it may lead to very poor timing results. It is
   recommended that this error condition be corrected in the design. A list of
   all the COMP.PINs used in this clock placement rule is listed below. These
   examples can be used directly in the .ucf file to override this clock rule.
   < NET "HREF" CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE = FALSE; >
   ERROR:Pack:1654 - The timing-driven placement phase encountered an error.
```

I just want to use external HREF signal as the trigger to count lines and for some other things. Is there a better way to configure logic? Here's what I have:

```
ENTITY mainModule IS
PORT(
    CLK160  :   IN  STD_LOGIC;
    BUFOUT  :   OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (11 DOWNTO 0)  := (OTHERS => '0');
    RESET_B :   OUT STD_LOGIC                       := '1';
    HREF    :   IN  STD_LOGIC;
    DATA_IM :   IN  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 DOWNTO 0);
    PCLK    :   IN  STD_LOGIC;
    XVCLK   :   OUT STD_LOGIC                       := '0');

END mainModule;

ARCHITECTURE BEHAVIORAL OF mainModule IS
    SIGNAL      CLK10       : STD_LOGIC     := '0';
    SIGNAL      SKIP        : STD_LOGIC     := '0';
    SIGNAL      LineCounter : UNSIGNED(9 DOWNTO 0)  := (OTHERS => '0');

    component CLK_DIV16 is  port (CLKIN : in STD_LOGIC; CLKDV : out STD_LOGIC );end component;

BEGIN
U1: CLK_DIV16 port map(CLKIN => CLK160,CLKDV => CLK10);

OUT_TEST: PROCESS(PCLK)
    BEGIN
        IF RISING_EDGE(PCLK) THEN
            BUFOUT(9 DOWNTO 0) <= DATA_IM(9 DOWNTO 0);
        ELSE NULL;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS OUT_TEST;

LINECOUNT: PROCESS (HREF)
    BEGIN
        IF RISING_EDGE(HREF) THEN
            IF  LineCounter > 488 THEN
                LineCounter <= (OTHERS => '0');
                SKIP <= NOT SKIP;
            ELSE    LineCounter <= LineCounter + 1;
            END IF;
        ELSE NULL;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS LINECOUNT;

BUFOUT(11)  <= PCLK AND HREF AND SKIP;  
XVCLK           <= CLK10;

END Behavioral;
```

Comment: See the answer at [ERROR:Pack:1654 - The timing-driven placement phase encountered an error](http://www.edaboard.com/thread280091.html) for a simpler explanation.

Comment: @DavidKoontz That explanation is simpler, but still over my head. It's true that _HREF_ is in bank0 and _BUFOUT_ is in the bank1. And I can not change this because it is routed on the board. Is it possible to change software? The function is simple: a counter and an AND-gate, should I rewrite the processes different way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume from the presense of `IOB` and `BUFGMUX` and .UCF that this must be a Xilinx FPGA. Note that as I work in the industry I use Verilog, but I think I can more or less follow what's going on in the VHDL code.

**Background: what is this Global Clock Distribution**

Clock signals are special because they need to arrive at all of the flip-flops *throughout the entire FPGA chip* at exactly the same time. Here I mean routing in the actual silicon and metal of the FPGA chip, not routing in the sense of configurable logic. These are hard, metal, permanent routes. The only configurable part about these global clock routes is which external clock pin supplies the clock signal and which flip-flops listen to this clock. If the clock distribution was not carefully routed by the FPGA manufacturer, then the flip-flops that are closer to the clock pin would capture their inputs sooner than flip-flops that are placed farther away -- and the design would no longer be synchronous logic. So to make the FPGA support the use of synchronous logic throughout the entire chip, there are some special `global clock` routes that are dedicated to distributing a clock signal from one of the dedicated clock inputs, to every flip-flop on the entire FPGA, such that the clock edge arrives at exactly the same time at each flip-flop. (Even if your design doesn't configure the flip-flop to connect to that clock, the FPGA silicon still has to contain the route. FPGA configuration can only enable routes that are already built into the chip.)

These global clock routes are "expensive" because each one spans an entire layer of the FPGA chip, so typically there are very few of these routes on the chip. This is OK because clocking is a one-to-many relationship (one clock driving many flip-flops), most designs use only 1 or 2 clocks anyway. And, typical HDL designs use recognizable synchronous logic constructs, like state machines. The HDL compiler can recognize a state machine or a bunch of flip-flops that share the same clock domain.

**What the error message means**

Xilinx requires the use of some special primitive constructs in their RTL code to route a clock signal onto these global clock routes, this is the `BUFG` (global clock buffer) or `BUFGMUX` (global clock multiplexer) that the error message references. `IOB` is a generic input/output buffer associated with a pin. And -- there are only a few special dedicated clock input pins (`IOB`) that can drive any of the global clock distribution systems (`BUFGMUX`). So the error message is telling you that you can't use that pin (that the `HREF` is assigned to) as a clock input (as the VHDL code requires).

**Why the error message?**

When the HDL compiler translates your VHDL source code, the synthesis tools infer from the expression `RISING_EDGE(PCLK)` that the `PCLK` input is a clock. So far, so good. But then the synthesis tools infer from the expression `RISING_EDGE(HREF)` that the `HREF` input is **another clock**. This is a problem. Your design doesn't really address split clock domains, clearly you intended to use `HREF` as a control input not a clock. And, unlike `PCLK`, the `HREF` signal is not assigned to an input pin that can receive an external clock. It's just not physically possible. The FPGA silicon chip doesn't have a configurable pathway from that particular pin's `IOB` to any global clock `BUFG`.

As your HDL code is written now, the `HREF` rising edge would be detected *immediately*, as though it was another clock signal. But then the `SKIP` signal is treated as if it was in the same clock domain as `PCLK`.

It's good to read up on the Xilinx literature about what these clock primitives are and how to use them; I recently had a project where I needed to select between an on-board clock and an optional user-supplied clock, and use with a couple of internal `DCM` (digital PLL sort of clock multiplier), and for that one I did have to "manually" instantiate all of the `IOB` and `BUFGMUX` and connect them "manually" because there were several clock domains of different frequencies.

**For most projects you don't have to worry about any of this.** As long as the synchronous logic all uses one clock ( Verilog `always @(posedge clk)` or VHDL `RISING_EDGE(CLK)`), and the clock is assigned to one of the special dedicated clock input pins, then the HDL compiler automatically determines where it needs `BUFGMUX` and `IOB`, and it silently inserts these as part of the normal synthesis. The only reason you got this error message was because your HDL code looked like it was using a clock signal that wasn't physically capable of being a clock.

**What to do about it**

A better approach is to modify your `LINECOUNT:` process to use `RISING_EDGE(PCLK)` so it is in the same clock domain as the rest of the design, and detect the rising edge on the `HREF` control input by using a flip-flop and comparing to the current `HREF` value. Store the previous `HREF` value as `HREF_PREVIOUS` ( I think in VHDL you use   `HREF_PREVIOUS <= HREF` thereby inferring a flip-flop). When `HREF_PREVIOUS` is 0 and `HREF` is 1, then you have detected the rising edge *during that PCLK clock cycle* -- and can trigger the `LineCounter` action and determine the next value of `SKIP`.

As a control input rather than a second clock, the `HREF` control input cannot be faster than `PCLK`, or else it will not be reliably detectable. This design assumes that the master clock `PCLK` is the fastest timing signal.

**What if you really meant to use two clocks?**

If in the future you do have a design that really does require splitting the logic across multiple clock domains, the usual technique for sending signals across the clock domain split involves a chain of 3 flip-flops (one in the source clock domain followed by two in the destination clock domain), to try to avoid metastable operation. Again, I don't think that's what you're trying to do here.

**What NOT to do about it**

If you really really really want the HDL compiler to route a clock signal (badly) from that `HREF` pin (*which is physically impossible to connect to the FPGA's internal global clock distribution system*), to drive a flip-flop (*from some random signal instead of the usual global clock system*), the error message text you posted does tell you how to override the error message. In your **project's .ucf file** (User Configuration File), you would add the `CLOCK_DEDICATED_ROUTE` attribute. (*Note Xilinx .UCF is only for the older ISE and XST tool; Vivado has a different kind of constraint system.*) And the performance would not be very good, so you'd have to keep everything at a slower clock speed to allow everything more time to settle. Really though that's probably a bad way to hack, unless you understand what's going on at the level of the FPGA primitive elements. (Technique would be OK if you were building a massive ripple counter using all of the flip-flops... but again, why would be trying to build a crummy ripple counter.) On balance, it's usually easier to write clean HDL code that synthesizes what you want, instead of trying to force a bad solution.

**More tips**

I notice this code is written as `Behavioral`... which is OK, but just remember that this is a Hardware Description Language, not a C compiler. If you want to successfully design code that can be synthesized, always keep in mind what the actual hardware is that you're describing. I come from a background of 25+ years as a C programmer, and it's a constant struggle for me to see the HDL code in terms of the actual hardware. Structural description (wiring connection) is closer to what will actually be synthesized. The synthesis tools can *usually* recognize what is intended from a behavioral description if you stick with commonly used forms, but it's very easy to confuse the synthesis tools and end up describing something that can't be built.

Get in the habit of skimming through the reams of output that the HDL compiler generates. It can be a bit overwhelming at first, but since you're starting with some small entry-level teaching circuits, it should be manageable. Xilinx ISE lets you view the RTL code post-synthesis, this is a good way to check that nothing important is left out. (I once had an error in a verilog `initial` block that only triggered a warning message, not an error... but it made the output of that module constant 0. And so that module was silently trimmed out because it had become a do-nothing module. And everything else that used that module got trimmed out too. Spent nearly a day trying to figure out why my custom SPI interface wasn't driving any output, then looked at RTL schematic and there was no SPI output pin. The actual output pin just wasn't being driven by any active HDL code. Almost half of my design was silently ripped out and trashed, all because of one little warning message.)

Comment: I am getting this same error on my `RESET` signal in my design.  I literally only have `rising_edge(CLK)` in all of my source files. -_-